# Magento 2: Updating Module Specific CSS

Tags: magento2, css, magento2.4, module-development

I have added a module specific css file from within a module.

I have a layout file at app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/modulestyles.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

I then placed a css file at app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/css/modulestyles.css with the following contents:

```
div {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

This works properly and I get all the divs with blue backgrounds.  However I am having an issue when I change the contents of the css file.  The only way I can get the site to update to the newer css is by clearing out pub/static and var/view_preprocessed and then refreshing the page (if I am in developer mode) or running a static deploy with this command if I am in production mode:

```
bin/magento s:s:d
```

My issue is that the page takes quite a while to reload the page in developer mode or to do the static deploy.  Is there no quicker way to update a module based css file?

Answer (score 0):

Your steps seem correct. Maybe your browser cache got in the way. If you use google chrome, hold down the refresh button and use Hard Reload.

sometimes a CDN (Content Delivery Network) hold old files as well.

If still no look, load the CSS in your bowser driectly.